# Using Azure B2C Identity Experience Framework to call custom functions

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have create a working function, we need to use B2C Identity Experience Framework to call it. The App is not calling the function.  The function URL has been specified in the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file.

Is this possible?  And if so, what do I need to do?

Comment: You need to be more elaborative about the scenario. You trying to call Web API (REST) from B2C Advanced policy?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible.  Here are 5 articles on learn.microsoft.com that show various ways to interact with APIs.  The first and second specifically use an Azure Function.  The function URL is specified in the Technical Profile (TP), that TP is then called in an orchestration step during user journey execution.

Regards,
J

1. [Walkthrough: Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C user journey as validation on user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom)
2. [Walkthrough: Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C user journey as an orchestration step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom)
3. [Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C user journey as validation of user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw)
4. [Secure your RESTful services by using HTTP basic authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw-secure-basic)
5. [Secure your RESTful service by using client certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw-secure-cert)

Answer (score 0):

To call external service call during login and registration, please see my article where I explained step by step how to do it using custom policies in the Azure AD B2C Identity Experience Framework:

[Azure AD B2C Series - external service call during login and registration](https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Azure-AD-B2C-Series-External-Service-Call/)